# Plant and Vegetable kept against drishti dosham at house entrances

Tags: tradition

Aloe Vera and Ash gourd are sometimes suspended at the house entrance during *Grihapravesam* ceremonies in some parts of India. ls there any spiritual basis or  early references for such tradition/ practice?